# Periodic short freezes after new fresh installation

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, freeze, input

I have the problem that my screen and input freezes for approx 1 sec about every 30 sec. I have googled a bit and found that this symptom has showed up with several different actual causes. For example something repated to upower. However, none of the solutions I have found have worked in my case. So I'm asking, what is a good starting point to try to locate the error? I would think, for example, that something would appear in dmesg every time the problem happens that would indicate the source of the problem. But nothing there... Ideas where to look anyone?

Btw, I have an Intel graphics chip:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Did you find anything suspicious in the log files? I'd particularly look at the kernel logs as well and the xorg logs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I looked at syslog, the log you get when typing dmesg (that's the kernel log, right?) and the x log. Nothing there.. :( Should I try to increase the loglevel or something? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If those freezes occurred when your mouse pointer is at the bottom right corner of your screen, try to install the latest proprietary driver from AMD site.

Comment: No it occurs regardless of where the mouse pointer is. Why should I download an AMD driver when I have an Intel graphics chip set? Or is it a driver for something other than graphics?